# My computer don't see any audio outputs

Tags: drivers, sound, ubuntu-drivers, audio-jack

i was trying to change some jack port functions by using hdajackretask, and my computer don't see any audio outputs now, My sound card is Conexant CX20751/2
Do you have any ideas how to fix it? (remove boot override doesn't help)